# How to return the newly persisted entity using the reactive extensions for hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mutiny, hibernate-reactive

I am trying to use mutiny in order to persist an entity. The add method should return a `Uni<Entity>` referencing the newly persisted (or merged) entity (I am using the `isPersistent` flag to determine whether an entity was already persisted previously). I also need a reference to the entity's updated id if it was generated by hibernate.

```
    @Override
    public Uni<Entity> add(Entity entity) {
        if(entity.isPersistent()){
            return sessionFactory.withSession(s ->s.merge(entity));
        }else{
            entity.markAsPersistent();
            return sessionFactory.withSession(s ->s.persist(entity)); // Error!
        }
    }
```

However, `s.persist()` returns a `Uni<Void>`.
I tried to modify the code as follows (which results in a detached entity):

```
return sessionFactory.withSession(s ->s.persist(entity).chain(s::flush).replaceWith(entity));
```

How should I proceed to map the `Uni<Void>` to a corresponding `Uni<Entity>`, which is not in a detached state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "replace" the return value of the second block:

```java
@Override
public Uni<Entity> add(Entity entity) {
    if (entity.isPersistent()) {
        return sessionFactory.withSession(s -> s.merge(entity));
    } else {
        entity.markAsPersistent();
        return sessionFactory.withSession(s -> s.persist(entity))
                             .replaceWith(() -> entity);
    }
}
```